# Running JIRA on a VM

Tags: version-control, virtual-machine, jira

Anyone have any success or failure running Jira on a VM?

I am setting up a new source control and defect tracking server.  My server room is near full and my services group suggested a VM.  I saw that a bunch of people are running SVN on VM (including NCSA).  The VM would also free me from hardware problems and give me high availability.  Finally, it frees me from some red tape and it can be implemented faster.

So, does anyone know of any reason why I shouldn't put Jira on a VM?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be careful using the term "VM" when it comes to Java apps.... *every* java app runs in a VM....

Comment: I've seen weird slowdowns on VMs that disappeared when we transitioned to physical, but more often than not, I run Atlassian products in VMs anyway. Be sure to give it a large resource allocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you shouldn't run jira off a vm - but jira needs a good amount of resources, and if your vm resides on a heavily loaded machine, it may exhibit poor performance. Why not log a support request (support.atlassian.com) and ask?

Comment: I asked Atlassian and they did the vendor two step.  They said that its not officially supported but that some customers used VMs.

Comment: you can try these instructions, may be they can help http://blogs.atlassian.com/developer/2009/04/setting_up_jira_and_confluence.html

Answer (score 10):

We just did the research for this, this is what we found:

- If you are planning to have a small number of projects (10-20) with 1,000 to 5,000 issues in total and about 100-200 users, a recent server (2.8+GHz CPU) with 256-512MB of available RAM should cater for your needs.
- If you are planning for a greater number of issues and users, adding more memory will help. We have reports that allocating 1GB of RAM to JIRA is sufficient for 100,000 issues.
- For reference, Atlassian's JIRA site (http://jira.atlassian.com/) has over 33,000 issues and over 30,000 user accounts. The system runs on a 64bit Quad processor. The server has 4 GB of memory with 1 GB dedicated to JIRA.

For our installation (<10000 issues, <20 concurrent sessions at a time) we use very little server resources (<1GB Ram, running on a quad-core processor we typically use <5% with <30% peak), and VM didn't impact performance in any measurable ammount.

Answer (score 4):

We run Jira on a virtual machine - VMWare running Windows Server 2003 SE and storing data on our SQL Server 2000 server. No problems, works well.

Answer (score 4):

My company moved our JIRA instance from a hosted physical server to an Amazon EC2 instance recently, and everything is holding up pretty well.  We're using an m1.large instance (64-bit o/s with 4 virtual cores and 8GB RAM), but that's way more than we need just for JIRA; we're also hosting Confluence and our corporate Web site on the same EC2 instance.

Note that we are a relatively small outfit; our JIRA instance has 25 users (with maybe 15 of them active) and about 1000 JIRA issues so far.

Answer (score 4):

We run our JIRA (and other Atlassian apps) instance on Linux-based VM instances. Everything run very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Disk access speed with JIRA on VM...

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Testing+Disk+Access+Speed

I'm wondering if the person who is using JIRA with VM (Chris Latta) is running ESX underneath - that may be faster than a windows host.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to run Jira, Bamboo, and FishEye from a set of virtual machines all hosted from the same server.  Although I would not recommend this setup for production in most shops.  Jira has fairly low requirements by today's standards. Just be sure you can allow enough resources from your host machine things should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

If, by VM, you mean a virtual instance of an OS, such as an instance of linux running on Xen, VMWare, or even Amazon EC2, then Jira will run just fine.  The only time you need to worry about virtual systems is if you're doing something that depends on hardware, such as running graphical 3D apps, or say something that uses a fax modem or a Digium telephony card with Asterisk.